# Is the word block in 'block D' capitalized?

Tags: grammar

When referring to an apartment block?  Should it be: Block D, or block D?

Comment: Is it a proper name? If so, yes. If not, no.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because proofreading requests are off-topic here.

Comment: @NeilFein I would argue that it is not a proofreading request. The question can be applied to any similar capitalization situation IMO.

Answer (score 1):

**Block D**

You capitalize proper *names*. The reason 'Block' is capitalized is because you are referring to a specific block. 'The block' would not be capitalized, because - while you are referring to a particular block - you are not naming it. Similarly, if you were to say 'the D blocks,' that too would not be capitalized. While referring to specific blocks, you are not specifying which D block you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You would say 'Block D' when referring to a place.